# FB Open Graph: Using the same action for different objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My app has 2 completely different objects that semantically require the same open graph action: 
'complete a scene' and 'complete a quest'.

Facebook has the following sentence in its 'Open Graph Checklist':

> Multiple objects: Do not submit duplicate or synonymous actions. For example, do not submit action:run and object:race, as well as action:run and object:marathon. Instead, submit one action (run) with two objects (race and marathon).

When i'm now adding 2 different objects to my action 'complete' in the Open Graph App Settings both of the objects are 'required' without the option to change this. What i want is to be able to post either 'complete quest' **OR** 'complete scene', not both of the objects in one post.

**Is it possible to comply with the Open Graph Checklist and use one action for completely different Objects?**

I know there are a few questions that sound alike but they all have different problems: some want to use multiple objects in one Post to Open Graph, some want objects to be connected to other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i'm now adding 2 different objects to my action 'complete' in the Open Graph App Settings both of the objects are 'required' without the option to change this.

The Open Graph overview for your action says both objects are “required”, yes – but you can still publish an action with only *one* of those objects given.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe! I wouldn't have guessed that :)